# Project a point perpendicular FROM a line segment onto another line segment

Tags: geometry

How can I find a point Q on line segment CD such that point P is projected perpendicularly from line segment AB onto line segment CD? So far I have only come across orthogonal projection ONTO another line segment but I want to do an orthogonal projection FROM a line segment. AB and CD are non-perpendicular and non-collinear.

```
Known:
Line segment 1: A(X,Y) to B(X,Y)
Line segment 2: C(X,Y) to D(X,Y)
Point to project: P(X,Y)

Unknown:
Q(X,Y)
```

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2AML.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let vector

```
CD = D - C
```

In parametric form point `Q` at segment `CD`:

```
Q = C + t * CD          (1)
```

Vector `PQ`

```
PQ = Q - P = C + t * CD - P
```

it is perpendicular to `AB` or `AP`, so dot product is zero

```
(C + t * (D - C) - P).dot.(P - A) = 0
```

Now solve this equation for unknown parameter `t`

```
t = (AP.dot.CP) / (AP.dot.CD)
```

and get point `Q` using (1)

[image]

Python example:

```
def backproj(ax, ay, px, py, cx, cy, dx, dy):
    cdx = dx - cx
    cdy = dy - cy
    apx = px - ax
    apy = py - ay
    denom = cdx*apx+cdy*apy
    if denom == 0:
        return None  #case of perpendicular segments
    t = (apx*(px-cx)+apy*(py-cy)) / denom
    if t < 0 or t > 1:
        return None    #case of point outside CD segment
    qx = cx + cdx * t
    qy = cy + cdy * t
    return qx, qy

print(backproj(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5))
print(backproj(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5))
print(backproj(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5))

>>>
None
None
(1.0, 2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Equation of `AB`:

   ```
             (yB - yA)
    y = yA + --------- (x - xA)
             (xB - xA)
   ```
2. Equation of `CD`:

   ```
            (yD - yC)
   y = yC + --------- (x - xC)
            (xD - xC)
   ```
3. Equation of `PQ`: orthogonal to `AB`

   ```
            (xA - xB)
   y = yP + --------- (x - xP)
            (yB - yA)
   ```

Point `Q` is at intersection of `CD` and `PQ`; solving the system of two equations (2) and (3), you get the value of `xQ`, then the value of `yQ` by replacing `x` by `xQ` in equation (3).